# What do we call darker, deeper, richer colors?

Tags: color, color-theory, terminology, color-profile, color-spaces

Burgundy, Forest Green, Navy/Royal Blue, to me, all have a darker, richer shade than their primary color counterparts. We identify lighter, duller shades as pastel, do we have a word for darker and richer?

Comment: Seems "deep" or "dark" are common terms. I don't think there's anything more. But I'd be interested if there is.

Comment: the problem with this question is that it asks clarification or new term for a description. But in this case since all we have is your description you get description=description. So the way the question is set up without any image leads us to the answer darker and deep color. But generally pastels have a name because we want to differentiate them from nonmoniker names which are the fully saturated colors.

Comment: I can’t think of a better word than “deep”, but I get the impression that the phenomena of a darker shade appearing the most strongly coloured applies more to the cool hues of green, blue and purple than the warm hues of red, orange and yellow. Do other people get that same impression?

Comment: More saturated?